# Netbeans and SVN

Tags: svn, netbeans

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. I installed netbeans 7.0.1 and subversion 1.16.17, both from the repositories. When I click on Team-Subversion-Checkout nothing happens. When I enter the path to executable /usr/bin in Tools-Options-Misc-Versioning-Subversion and click OK, the checkout still doesnt work. When I reenter the options menu the path is not there. Seems like it isnt saved.

Comment: I managed to get the executable path in the field by editing the file ~/.netbeans/7.0/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/subversion.properties. The path is now also shown in the GUI options menu.
My subversion.properties looks like this:
`annotationFormat=[{status} {folder}]
annotator.annotationExp.0=\\2
annotator.urlExp.0=.*/(branches|tags)/(.+?)(/.*)?
autoOpenOutput=true
excludeNewFiles=false
prefixRepositoryPath=false
svnExecBinary=/usr/bin`

Comment: too be honest with you, netbeans svn plugin never worked for me, I am using git at the moment, and that works as a charm. You should consider using git.

Answer (score 4):

I've found a solution for this bug that happens just in netbeans installations that comes from debian repository packets, and it's related directly with permissions over some files in the installation, this is a work around to solve it:

*Subversion plugin was not installed correctly so*

- run: `sudo netbeans`
- uninstall subversion plugin
- quit netbeans
- run: netbeans  (Note that now you're running it as a regular user not like root)
- go to Tools->Plugins->[Settings]
- add offical plugins repositories
- change to "available plugins" tab and install subversion plugin

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution for this bug that happens just in netbeans installations that comes from debian repository packets, and it's related directly with permissions over some files in the installation, this is a work around to solve it:

Subversion plugin was not installed correctly so

```
-run: sudo netbeans 
-uninstall subversion plugin 
-quit netbeans 
-run: netbeans (Note that now you're running it as a regular user not like root) 
-go to Tools->Plugins->[Settings] 
-add offical plugins repositories 
-change to "available plugins" tab and install subversion plugin
```

Hope it helps!